# GETTING THIS [Error] Execution (25: 14): ORA-00984: column not allowed here WHEN TRYING TO INSERT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

HERE'S THE TABLE I CREATED:

```
CREATE TABLE personal_info (
  Person_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Date_of_Birth DATE,
  Join_date DATE,
  Join_year NUMBER,
  Person_address VARCHAR(75),
  Person_Post VARCHAR(15),
  Person_id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Email_primary VARCHAR(30),
  Phone_primary NUMBER,
  Email_secondary VARCHAR(30),
  Phone_secondary NUMBER,
  
  Sal_grade CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  Empl_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Salary_Person FOREIGN KEY (Sal_grade) REFERENCES salary(Salary_grade) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Person FOREIGN KEY (Empl_id) REFERENCES employee(Employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  
  CONSTRAINT UC_Person_ID UNIQUE (Empl_id,Person_name)
);
```

HERE'S THE EMPLOYEE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  Employee_id NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Employee_job_description VARCHAR(200),
  Proj_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  Dep_id NUMBER NOT NULL
);
  
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_project_employee 
FOREIGN KEY (Proj_id) REFERENCES PROJECTS(Project_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dept_employee 
FOREIGN KEY (Dep_id) REFERENCES dept(Dept_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE SEQUENCE EMPID_SEQ1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999
START WITH 10000
INCREMENT BY 4
CACHE 20;
```

I ALREADY INSERTED INTO THE EMPLOYEE TABLE, NO ISSUE.

```
INSERT INTO employee (Employee_id, Employee_job_description, Proj_id, Dep_id) VALUES(EMPID_SEQ1.NEXTVAL,'SENIOR VICE PRESIDENT',501,1);
```

BUT WHEN I TRY TO INSERT INTO THE PERSONAL_INFO TABLE:

```
/* Formatted on 19-Oct-22 11:58:19 AM (QP5 v5.256.13226.35538) */
INSERT INTO PERSONAL_INFO (Empl_id,
                           Person_name,
                           Date_of_Birth,
                           Join_date,
                           Join_year,
                           Person_address,
                           Sal_grade,
                           Actual_salary,
                           Person_Post,
                           PERSON_ID,
                           Email_primary,
                           Phone_primary,
                           Email_secondary,
                           Phone_secondary)
     VALUES (EMPID_SEQ1.CURRVAL,
             'Mr. FF',
             TO_DATE ('1980/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
             TO_DATE ('2000/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
             TO_CHAR (Join_DATE, 'YYYY'),
             'Banani,Dhaka.',
             'D',
             150000,
             'SVP',
             TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(Join_YEAR) || TO_CHAR (EMPID_SEQ1.CURRVAL)),
             'FF@bank.com',
             01234567891,
             'FFF@bank.com',
             99998882222);
```

I GET THE AFORMENTIONED ERROR WHILE INSERTING THE PERSON_ID UNIQUE KEY VALUE. BASICALLY I WANTED THE PERSON_ID TO LOOK SOMETHING LIKE '200710016'. JOINING YEAR FOLLOWED BY EMPLOYEE ID.

BUT IT'S TELLING ME THAT THE JOIN_YEAR COLUMN IS NOT ALLOWED HERE.

Comment: While writing all upper-case is common for SQL, please don't do that for normal text. For normal text and sentences, writing in all upper-case is considered *shouting*, and it very rude to shout at the people you want to help you. Please [edit] your question and rewrite without the caps-lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a column that's just being inserted - you'll have to "repeat" the same data again.

Also, target table should be modified (two datatypes - phone numbers aren't really "numbers" because of possible leading zeros; one column is missing).

As of the sequence, you first have to select `nextval` and then `currval` because - initially - `currval` doesn't exist.

When fixed:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE personal_info
  2  (
  3     Person_name       VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  4     Date_of_Birth     DATE,
  5     Join_date         DATE,
  6     Join_year         NUMBER,
  7     Person_address    VARCHAR (75),
  8     Person_Post       VARCHAR (15),
  9     Person_id         VARCHAR (9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 10     Email_primary     VARCHAR (30),
 11     Phone_primary     VARCHAR (30),         --> change datatype
 12     Email_secondary   VARCHAR (30),
 13     Phone_secondary   VARCHAR (30),         --> change datatype
 14     Sal_grade         CHAR (1) NOT NULL,
 15     Empl_id           NUMBER NOT NULL,
 16     actual_salary     NUMBER                --> add this column
 17  );

Table created.
```

Insert:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO PERSONAL_INFO (Empl_id,
  2                             Person_name,
  3                             Date_of_Birth,
  4                             Join_date,
  5                             Join_year,
  6                             Person_address,
  7                             Sal_grade,
  8                             Actual_salary,
  9                             Person_Post,
 10                             PERSON_ID,
 11                             Email_primary,
 12                             Phone_primary,
 13                             Email_secondary,
 14                             Phone_secondary)
 15          VALUES (
 16                    EMPID_SEQ1.nextval,
 17                    'Mr. FF',
 18                    TO_DATE ('1980/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
 19                    TO_DATE ('2000/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
 20                    TO_CHAR (
 21                       TO_DATE ('2000/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
 22                       'YYYY'),
 23                    'Banani,Dhaka.',
 24                    'D',
 25                    150000,
 26                    'SVP',
 27                    TO_CHAR (
 28                          TO_CHAR (
 29                             TO_DATE ('2000/05/03 21:02:44',
 30                                      'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
 31                             'YYYY')
 32                       || TO_CHAR (EMPID_SEQ1.CURRVAL)),
 33                    'FF@bank.com',
 34                    '01234567891',
 35                    'FFF@bank.com',
 36                    '99998882222');

1 row created.
```

Comment: Okay thanks Littlefoot. I just described what I was trying to do with a colleague of mine and even he said what I was trying to do didn't make any conceptual sense. But I knew it was possible. And somehow you made it possible. So thanks again for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a `join_year` column in the table as the value can be calculated from the `join_date` column and if it is independent then the two columns can get out-of-sync. If you did want to have it in the table then it should be a virtual column. Similarly for `person_id` (although if there were business reasons to persist the `person_id` so that it could be changed later then you could set it with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger rather than using a virtual column, but either way you should not need to supply a default value derived from other columns in the `INSERT` statement):

```sql
CREATE TABLE personal_info (
  Person_name     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Date_of_Birth   DATE,
  Join_date       DATE,
  Join_year       NUMBER
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM join_date)),
  Person_address  VARCHAR(75),
  Person_Post     VARCHAR(15),
  Person_id       VARCHAR(9)
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                    CAST(
                      TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM join_date), 'FM0000')
                      || TO_CHAR(empl_id, 'FM00000')
                      AS VARCHAR2(9)
                    )
                  )
                  NOT NULL
                  UNIQUE,
  Email_primary   VARCHAR(30),
  Phone_primary   VARCHAR2(12),
  Email_secondary VARCHAR(30),
  Phone_secondary VARCHAR2(12),
  Sal_grade       /* CHAR(1) */ NOT NULL,
  Actual_Salary   NUMBER(10,2),
  Empl_id         /* NUMBER */ NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Salary_Person FOREIGN KEY (Sal_grade)
    REFERENCES salary(Salary_grade) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_Person FOREIGN KEY (Empl_id)
    REFERENCES employee(Employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT UC_Person_ID UNIQUE (Empl_id, Person_name)
);
```

*Note: You do not need to include the data type when a column has a foreign key constraint; if you omit it then the column will take the same data type as the primary/unique key it is referencing and you can ensure consistency between the tables.*

*Note 2: The `EMPID_SEQ1` sequence starts with 10000 and increases by 4 to a maximum of 9999999 and the `Person_id` column can take 9 characters, of which 4 are the year so once there are 22500 people in the table and the sequence gets to 100000 then it will be too large for the `Person_id` column. You should probably either limit the sequence to 99999 or make the `Person_id` column larger.*

*Note 3: While phone numbers are numeric, they often have leading zeroes and these will not be stored in a `NUMBER` column so you should store phone numbers as a `VARCHAR2`.*

*Note 4: You are missing the `actual_salary` column.*

Then you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO PERSONAL_INFO (
  Empl_id,
  Person_name,
  Date_of_Birth,
  Join_date,
  Person_address,
  Sal_grade,
  Actual_salary,
  Person_Post,
  Email_primary,
  Phone_primary,
  Email_secondary,
  Phone_secondary
) VALUES (
  EMPID_SEQ1.CURRVAL,
  'Mr. FF',
  TO_DATE ('1980/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  TO_DATE ('2000/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  'Banani,Dhaka.',
  'D',
  150000,
  'SVP',
  'FF@bank.com',
  '01234567891',
  'FFF@bank.com',
  '99998882222'
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9OGMEuqp)